# How to override dialog close function?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I encapsulate dialog service to add some  options like animation,

and i trying to override close function :

```
 const closeFunction = dialogRef.close;
 const closeHandler = (dialogResult?: R) => {
        wrapper.animate([keyFrame0, keyFrame100], { duration: 1000, easing: 'ease-out' });
        setTimeout(() => closeFunction(dialogResult), 500);
      };
 dialogRef.close = (dialogResult?: R) => closeHandler(dialogResult);
```

The error when closing the dialog:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '_result' of undefined
```

what should i need to do else? some binding?
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxcktc?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score -1):

The way `closeFunction` has been defined is not a valid function. To make your example work, the close function needs to accept the dialog as parameter or react in case it is undefined. Try this:

```
const closeFunction = (dialog?) => {
  if ( dialog ) {
     // Valid dialog
     dialog.close
  } else {
    // Undefined dialog
    console.log( 'Dialog does not exist' );
  }
};

const closeHandler = (dialog?) => {
   closeFunction(dialog)
};

dialogRef.close = (dialog?) => {
   closeHandler(dialog);
}
```

**EDIT**

The code above gets rid of the error message from the console but does not actually overwrite the close function. I don't think it's possible to overwrite the function directly, but a workaround is to define a new method, i.e., `customClose` which applies custom code and then closes the dialog. Here's how it works:

```
// Declare a new method (customClose) on the dialogRef after dialog opens
// This new method stores the logic you want to apply before closing
dialogRef['customClose'] = () => {
   console.log( 'Apply 2 seconds animation here' );
   setTimeout(() => dialogRef.close() , 2000);
}

// Then, on the onNoClick method call the custom method instead
onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef['customClose']();
}
```

The actual animation part has not been covered. You can see it in action by checking the console on [this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxcktc-jnoyb1?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Comment: The function 'close' does not accept dialog as a parameter.

Comment: @yantrab I understand. My original reply was focused on the removing the error but did not cover the actual overwrite of the 'close' function. Please take a look at my edit above. I have added a link to a new fork with a working example.